# Xamarin.Android cannot catch Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, maui, .net-7.0

I have just migrated Xamarin app to net7.0 from netstandard2.0 and I'm faced a Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException which i cannot catch.
I've added HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback. For certificates which are not valid I'm returning 'false'. Xamarin.Android throw this exception, and exception appears to be unhandled despite I have try/catch around HttpClient.SendAsync function. How I can catch this exception in try/catch?

Stack trace is next:

```
at Xamarin.Android.Net.ServerCertificateCustomValidator.TrustManager.CheckServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] javaChain, String authType) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/ServerCertificateCustomValidator.cs:line 72\n   
at Javax.Net.Ssl.IX509TrustManagerInvoker.n_CheckServerTrusted_arrayLjava_security_cert_X509Certificate_Ljava_lang_String_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_chain, IntPtr native_authType) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Javax.Net.Ssl.IX509TrustManager.cs:line 132\n   
at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLL_V(_JniMarshal_PPLL_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0, IntPtr p1) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 187\n  

--- End of managed Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException stack trace ---\n
java.security.cert.CertificateException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.\n\t
at xamarin.android.net.ServerCertificateCustomValidator_TrustManager.n_checkServerTrusted(Native Method)\n\t
at xamarin.android.net.ServerCertificateCustomValidator_TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(ServerCertificateCustomValidator_TrustManager.java:42)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:260)\n\tat com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1638)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:569)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:858)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.-$$Nest$mprocessDataFromSocket(Unknown Source:0)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:241)\n\t
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:220)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)\n\t
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)\n
```

Code example:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Credentials = Credentials,
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = OnServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback,
};
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

try
{
    return await httpClient.SendAsync(
        requestMessage, completionOption, cancellationToken)
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // some loggine, ie
}
```

OnServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback breakpoint got a hit, I can validate certificates.

Comment: Please add your code to question. Show the try catch around sendasync. Also, set breakpoint; step through your code. Make sure that is the line that triggers the exception.

Comment: added code example

Comment: The Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException is android inner exception, can you detect which line causes or throws this exception?